# Cannot import pykinect2

Tags: python, kinect-v2, pykinect

I have installed KinectV2 SDK on my Windows 10 system and test it successfully inside SDK browsers.

I tried to run some code from Pykinect2 library but there was an issues while importing:

```
from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
      2 from pykinect2.PyKinectV2 import *

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\kinect-env\lib\site-packages\pykinect2\PyKinectV2.py:2216
   2131 ################################################################
   2132 ## code template for ICoordinateMapper implementation
   2133 ##class ICoordinateMapper_Impl(object):
   (...)
   2200 ##        #return colorPoint
   2201 ##
   2203 tagSTATSTG._fields_ = [
   2204     ('pwcsName', WSTRING),
   2205     ('type', c_ulong),
   (...)
   2214     ('reserved', c_ulong),
   2215 ]
-> 2216 assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) == 72, sizeof(tagSTATSTG)
   2217 assert alignment(tagSTATSTG) == 8, alignment(tagSTATSTG)
   2218 IAudioBeamList._methods_ = [
   2219     COMMETHOD(['propget'], HRESULT, 'BeamCount',
   2220               ( ['retval', 'out'], POINTER(c_uint), 'count' )),
   (...)
   2223               ( ['out'], POINTER(POINTER(IAudioBeam)), 'AudioBeam' )),
   2224 ]

AssertionError: 80
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a rather usual error (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972599/unable-to-run-pykinect2-on-python-3-11-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77292753/why-is-from-pykinect2-import-pykinectv2-not-working)). Here is the remedy according to a [thread](https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2/issues/36#issuecomment-449179253) in the PyKinect2 Github repo:

> assuming this is the same import error I received caused by the `assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) == 72` on line 2216 of PyKinectV2.py (`sizeof` is now 80) then the quick fix is to edit the file to `assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) >= 72`.
>
> My assumption is that an extra field has been added to the structure in the Microsoft API... by convention Microsoft have usually/always append any new fields to the end of structures so as not to break backwards compatability... anyhow it allowed me to successfuly import PyKinectV2.

Notice that, according to your error trace, the error stems exactly from `assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) == 72` on line 2216 of `PyKinectV2.py`, as argued in the Github thread.

According to a relevant [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kinect/comments/12jk9il/trouble_installing_pykinect2_library_on_python/), changing the line to `assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) == 80` should also work.

In any case, you should keep in mind that [PyKinect2](https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2) seems abandoned since ~8 years ago.